# Advice needed: NewtonSoft.Json and Dynamics NAV 2009 R2 Classic

Tags: json, .net, dynamics-nav-2009

I'm trying to get the Codeunit 50000 in this zip file to work: https://kappiwebhosting.blob.core.windows.net/dynamcisis/2015/09/Json.zip
Found here: https://dynamics.is/?p=2303

[C/AL Globals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFsRL.png)

I'm trying to get Dynamics Nav 2009 to recognize the NewtonSoft.Json.dll, but no matter which version i try, i get this error as soon i want to verify the DotNet variable "JsonTextReader"/"JsonTextWriter" when selecting the subtype.

*.NET interop: exception occured, 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.'.*

If i declare a new Test variable of type DonNet and click [...] to select it from scratch i got this error when trying to choose which assembly to use:

*.NET interop: exception occured, 'Could not load file or assembly '**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics NAV\60\Classic\Add-ins\Newtonsoft.Json.dll**' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.'.*

The Newtonsoft.Json.dll file is present ind the folder, and "Everyone" have full control to the folder as well as the file.

The Json.zip file contain a single Newtonsoft.Json.dll which i started out with. Same error. The i downloaded the https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases and tried all versions with the same result.

Why all this? Yes, the company i work for have decided to start using Shopify, and i need to write an interface for getting orders from Shopify etc.

I really cannot figure out why i can't get this to work. There are 3 other DotNet "variables" that's configured and works as intended with no errors.

So any advice is highly appreciated.

Thanx

Comment: What is .Net framework version on your machine/server? You might need to update it.

Comment: Hi Mark

Thanks for replying.

This is what my pc is reporting:


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084 

best regards

lars